# Freshdesk JIRA integration using webhook

Tags: jira, freshdesk

I am trying to create ticket in freshdesk whenever I update a jira ticket. I setup a webhook for jira and calling freshdesk API to add ticket there.

my problem is when I update ticket it jira it'd triggering my webhook and create a ticket in freshdesk but freshdesk again posting it back to jira and it's working like an infinitloop.

any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two triggers:
1. Jira update -> new ticket in Freshdesk; and
2. Freshdesk ticket -> new issue in Jira.

Yes, that will try to create an infinite number of issues and tickets. So you have to ask yourself, "What am I trying to do?" The main thing I would ask you is which resource (Freshdesk or Jira) is the authoritative data source, and which resource is the dependant.

It could be that Jira is where bugs and feature requests are logged, and those requests trigger Freshdesk activities. In that case, you should only have a link from Jira to Freshdesk. Updating an issue in Freshdesk in this scenario is interesting, but not relevant to the Jira issue.

Comment: I'm using https://apps.freshdesk.com/jira/ for creating tickets in JIRA from Freshdesk but recently JIRA changed their webhook payload structure so JIRA to freshdesk update is not happening. So I implemented my own webhook and use Freshdesk to update the ticket from JIRA.